# Temasys library connection issue

Tags: azure, serviceconnection, temasys

I am compiling azure library gradle in sample app of Temasys library.

```
Azure library version: 
compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:3.0'

Temasys gradle: compile(group: 'sg.com.temasys.skylink.sdk', // This is example

name: 'skylink_sdk',
version: '0.9.5-RELEASE',
ext: 'aar') {
transitive = true
}
```

As soon, I compile this and sample app starts throwing connection issue. It keeps on connecting and disconnecting. Strange part is that there is no line of code related to azure. I am just compiling it by gradle.

```
I am attaching here logs.

Much appreciate any reply.


05-16 16:08:14.497 11889-12352/com.temasys.skylink.sampleapp D/cf: Peer 6Bxc6lQZ6oKVVOAdABid : onIceConnectionChange : iceState : CHECKING.
    05-16 16:08:14.593 11889-12352/com.temasys.skylink.sampleapp D/cf: [onIceGatheringChange] New ICE Gathering State is now: COMPLETE.
    05-16 16:08:15.657 11889-12352/com.temasys.skylink.sampleapp D/cf: Peer 6Bxc6lQZ6oKVVOAdABid : onIceConnectionChange : iceState : CONNECTED.
    05-16 16:08:15.658 11889-12352/com.temasys.skylink.sampleapp D/cf: Peer 6Bxc6lQZ6oKVVOAdABid : onIceConnectionChange : iceState : COMPLETED.
    05-16 16:08:15.672 11889-12351/com.temasys.skylink.sampleapp D/WebRtcAudioRecord: AcousticEchoCanceler.isAvailable: true
    05-16 16:08:15.725 11889-12351/com.temasys.skylink.sampleapp D/WebRtcAudioRecord: AcousticEchoCanceler name: Acoustic Echo Canceler, implementor: The Android Open Source Project, uuid: bb392ec0-8d4d-11e0-a896-0002a5d5c51b
    05-16 16:08:15.725 11889-12351/com.temasys.skylink.sampleapp D/WebRtcAudioRecord: AcousticEchoCanceler.getEnabled: true
    05-16 16:08:17.475 11889-12352/com.temasys.skylink.sampleapp D/cf: Peer 6Bxc6lQZ6oKVVOAdABid : onIceConnectionChange : iceState : CLOSED.
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed. A new version of the Skylink SDK for Android will be available in the next 1-2 weeks after additional release testing. If you are looking for an early pre-release candidate that addresses this issue please contact us at dev-support@temasys.com.sg